# IIS 7.5 Restful service returns Error 411 - length required from .net client but not fiddler

Tags: .net, wcf, rest, iis-7.5

I'm using a Microsoft Stack: Windows Server 2008 R2 / IIS 7.5; .NET 4.0

Setting up the service on localhost, the client call the operation without a hitch. Setting up the service (originally as a Post then as a Get) I get the following error from .NET (method below). If I make the call directly through fiddler everything works and the (RAW) header is as follows:

HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Cache-Control: private
Content-Length: 19854411
Content-Type: application/xml; charset=utf-8
Server: Microsoft-IIS/7.5
X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET

If I make a call through console app or windows service I get the following error
"The remote server returned an error: <411> Length Required."

I have a web service that is supposed to return a zip file after doing some work

```
    [OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(UriTemplate = "/GetFiles/{profileLocationId}/{batchSize}", Method = "GET", RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Xml, BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare)]
    public byte[] ProfileImagesByProfileId(string profileLocationId, string batchSize)
    {
        //  var watch = new Stopwatch();
        //  watch.Start();
        try
        {
            long id = 0;
            long.TryParse(profileLocationId, out id);

            int size = 200;
            int.TryParse(batchSize, out size);

            var profileRoot = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ProfileImageRootDirectory"];
            var fileType = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ProfileImageDefaultFileType"];


            var packer = new ImagePackager(profileRoot, fileType);
            if (profileLocationId != null)
            {
                var stream = packer.CompressImages(id, size);

                return stream;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return new byte[0];

        }

        return new byte[0];
    }
}
```

===========================

## client method

```
 static void TimerElapsed(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
        var id = GetLastProfileId();

       // var uri = string.Format("http://{0}/TwitterService/ProfileImages/{1}/{2}", _ipAddress, id, _batchsize);
        var uri = string.Format("http://{0}/Twitter_api/TwitterService/ProfileImages/{1}/{2}", _ipAddress, id, _batchsize);
        GetProfileImagesFromService(uri);
    }


    private static void GetProfileImagesFromService(string uri)
    {
        try
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Process started: {0}", DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString());
            var request = WebRequest.Create(uri);
            request.Method = "GET";
            request.Timeout = 600000;
            using (var response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse())
            {
                Console.WriteLine(response.StatusDescription);
                var dataStream = response.GetResponseStream();
                var reader = new StreamReader(dataStream, Encoding.UTF8);
                //  var responseFromServer = reader.ReadToEnd();

                var fileName = string.Format(@"{0}\{1:yyMMddhhmmss}.zip", _targetDirectory, DateTime.UtcNow);
                // File.WriteAllText(fileName, responseFromServer);
                // var xml = XDocument.Parse(responseFromServer);
                var xml = XDocument.Load(reader);
                var base64 = xml.Root.Value.ToCharArray();

                var byteArray = Convert.FromBase64CharArray(base64, 0, base64.Length);

                File.WriteAllBytes(fileName, byteArray);
                Console.WriteLine("GetProfile cycle ended: {0}", DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString());
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        }
    }
```

---

Any guidance would be extremely appreciated.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

HTTP Error Code 411 means

> The server refuses to accept the request without a defined Content- Length. The client MAY repeat the request if it adds a valid Content-Length header field containing the length of the message-body in the request message.

So if you are invoking HTTP POST method without any body then just add `Content-Length:0` in your request object in header.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I am doing a GET and Fiddler is telling me I have a valid content-length when looking at the RAW tab of the response. the WebInvoke makes this a restful call.

Comment: if you notice then you will see that Fiddler automatically adds the `content-length` header on this basis of body content. so when you are making call from your code then you can set it as 0 if there is no body.

Answer (score 0):

I had a customer getting 411 error and it turned out they had BitDefender antivirus that was causing the problem somehow. Disabling BitDefender fixed the problem. Server is IIS/ASP.NET on Windows Server (2012 or 2016?) and client AngularJS. Chrome dev tools showed the POST had Content-Length: 0 yet the server responded with 411 error, which we'd not seen before despite many other customers using it without problems.

So if you're getting this error on occasion I suggest looking for antivirus,  adblockers, etc that might be interrupting the client-server comms.